# Не работает поиск переменной в списке

Tags: python-3.x, поиск

Всем добрый день! Задача - выяснить, есть ли номер месяца в списке и если да - то напечатать время года. Вроде все просто, но поиск переменной в списке не работает. Причем ошибок не выдаёт, и отдебажить тоже невозможно, т.к. на этапе if - просто наступает тишина. Что не так в коде?

```
  month = input("Введите номер месяца в виде целого числа:")
    if not month.isdigit():
        print("Неверный формат числа")
        exit()
    spring = [3, 4, 5]

if month in spring:
    print("Весна")
```

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, метку используемого языка программирования (нажав [edit])

Comment: У `month` тип строка, а в `spring` объекты типа целое число. Сделайте их одного типа, приведите `month` к `int`

Comment: Я пытался уже привести month к int конструкцией int(month), но она не работает, увы... Только если сразу задавать int перед input...

Comment: upd: забыл объявить переменную month = int(month), сорри, все работает. спасибо!

Comment: @Сергей оберните input() в int(), что бы выглядело вот так mont = int(input('введите номер месяца...')

Answer (score 3):

можно вообще в лоб, чтоб не думать :)

```
months = {
    "1": "зима", "2": "зима", "3": "весна", "4": "весна", "5": "весна", "6": "лето", 
    "7": "лето", "8": "лето", "9": "осень", "10": "осень", "11": "осень", "12": "зима",
}

month = input("Введите номер месяца в виде целого числа:")
res = months.get(month, "фигню ввели")
print(res)
```

Comment: Лучше ещё сгруппировать внутри сезонов месяца списочком. Будет чуть сложнее структура, зато более нормализованная. А поиск не сильно сложнее будет. Ну, как дополнительный вариант, не основной.

Answer (score 1):

Можно побаловаться и вот так

```py
def which_season(month:int):
  if not isinstance(month, int): 
     print(f"Тип данных не подходит, нужен int, а не {type(month)}")
     return None
  if month not in range(1,13):
     print(f"Да, что же вы мне пихаете? {month} не лежит в промежутке от 1 до 12 ")
     return None
  return ["Зима", "Весна", "Лето", "Осень"][int(round((month % 12) / 3, 1))]
```

а теперь вот так

```py
for i in range(1,13):
  which_season(i)

"""вывод
'Зима'
'Зима'
'Весна'
'Весна'
'Весна'
'Лето'
'Лето'
'Лето'
'Осень'
'Осень'
'Осень'
'Зима'
"""
```

Или

```py
>>> which_season("bla")               
Тип данных не подходит, нужен int, а не <class 'str'>
>>> which_season(13)                                                            
Да, что же вы мне пихаете? 13 не лежит в промежутке от 1 до 12
```